# SQL: How to divide column by counts?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

So I have this query

```
SELECT distinct toner.device_id, printer.paper_count from toner 
join printer on printer.device_id = toner.device_id;
```

This will print something like

| device_id | paper_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 10000 |

And I have this other other query that will return the number of times the toner has been changed according to some date. I used count to count the number of times it's been changed.

```
select device_id, count(toner_color) as 'Change Count' from toner where 
toner_color = 'Black' group by device_id;
```

This will print something like

| device_id | Change Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

What I'm trying to get is the average amount of papers printed by 1 ink cannister e.g. 5000 paper / 2 black ink cannisters = 2500.

So I'm looking to get something like this

| device_id | paper_count | Change Count | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 2 | 2500 |
| 2 | 10000 | 2 | 5000 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would `group by p.device_id, p.paper_count`, while filtering by `where toner_color = 'Black'`:

```
select p.device_id, p.paper_count, count(toner_color) as 'Change Count'
    , round(p.paper_count / count(toner_color)) as 'Average'
from toner t join printer p on p.device_id = t.device_id
where toner_color = 'Black'
group by p.device_id, p.paper_count;
```

MySQL v.8.0 on [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sQ7MDacvoj2X7F4wjujaZN/1)

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a JOIN operation :

```
SELECT t1.device_id, t1.paper_count, t2.ChangeCount , (t1.paperCount / t2.ChangeCount) as Average  
FROM firsttable as t1 
JOIN secondtable as t2 on t1.device_id = t1.device_id;
```

this should be could!

Answer (score 1):

**Tables creation:**

```
CREATE TABLE printer(
device_id int(11),
paper_count int(11)
);

CREATE TABLE toner(
device_id int(11),
color varchar(32)
);
```

**Data insertion :**

```
INSERT INTO printer(device_id,paper_count) VALUES (1,5000),(2,10000);
INSERT INTO toner(device_id,color) VALUES (1,"Black"),(1,"Black"),(2,"Black"),(2,"Black"),(3,"White");
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT printer.device_id, printer.paper_count, count(toner.device_id) as change_count, (printer.paper_count / count(toner.device_id)) as Average  
FROM printer
JOIN toner on printer.device_id = toner.device_id
WHERE toner.color = "Black"
GROUP BY toner.device_id;
```

Output:

| device_id | paper_count | Change Count | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 2 | 2500 |
| 2 | 10000 | 2 | 5000 |

**Live solution:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3de92/1

Answer (score 1):

You almost there. Just combine that two query:

```
SELECT  *,
    paper_count/change_count average 
FROM
(

SELECT  toner.device_id,
    printer.paper_count,
    COUNT(toner_color) AS change_count
FROM    toner 
INNER
JOIN    printer ON printer.device_id = toner.device_id
WHERE   toner_color = "black"
GROUP BY toner.device_id
)
AS dbx
```

Explaination:

- INNER JOIN toner and printer.
- Use Condition: toner_color = Black
- GROUP BY toner.device_id to know about change_count per device ID
- After that, Average is Paper_count/change_count

[image: Your 1st and 2nd query]
[image: Combine them]